# lingmacros alignment causes compile failure

Tags: errors, linguistics, lingmacros

Without `&` for alignment, it works perfectly fine.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lingmacros}

\begin{document}

\enumsentence{\shortex{3}
  {Taroo$_i$-ga Yo$_j$-o zibun$_{i/*j}$-no shinshitsu-ni okutta.}
  {Taro-NOM Yo-ACC self-GEN bedroom-DAT sent}
  {`Taro$_i$ sent Yo$_j$ to his$_{i/*j}$ bedroom.'}
}

\end{document}
```

But when I add the `&`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lingmacros}

\begin{document}

\enumsentence{\shortex{3}
  {Taroo$_i$-ga & Yo$_j$-o & zibun$_{i/*j}$-no & shinshitsu-ni & okutta.}
  {Taro-NOM & Yo-ACC & self-GEN & bedroom-DAT & sent}
  {`Taro$_i$ sent Yo$_j$ to his$_{i/*j}$ bedroom.'}
}

\end{document}
```

I get

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> \unskip \hfil }\ \endtemplate 

l.10 }
```

Comment: The `lingmacros` package is very old.  Is there any reason why you're using it and not, e.g. `gb4e` or `linguex`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the right number of columns for your glosses.  Since your gloss line has 5 elements, you need to specify 5 columns.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lingmacros}

\begin{document}

\enumsentence{\shortex{5}
  {Taroo$_i$-ga & Yo$_j$-o & zibun$_{i/*j}$-no & shinshitsu-ni & okutta.}
  {Taro-NOM & Yo-ACC & self-GEN & bedroom-DAT & sent}
  {`Taro$_i$ sent Yo$_j$ to his$_{i/*j}$ bedroom.'}
}

\end{document}
```